# How can I verify the operating specification of a PCB?

Tags: pcb, testing, electronic-load, stress-testing

I have a couple of PCBs which work with each other: core PCB, middleware PCB and a peripheral PCB. All of them have a voltage and current rating along with protection circuits.

What tests can I perform to verify those specifications? I'm aware that I can put a load on the output, vary the load, vary the supply. Is there anything else I can do? I don't want the tests to be too in-depth. I just need  test plans that verify the operating specifications of the boards.

Comment: you should probably test that they're supposed to be working after (and while) you applied these conditions. So, that boils down to you sitting down and writing down what it is that these boards need to perform. We can't guess that!

Comment: This is all too vague. What is "voltage and current rating" in what context? What is "protection circuits" in what context? What are the boards actually for? What environment are they supposed to exist in? What requirements are there?

Comment: Marcus makes a very excellent point. Did your design team communicate with you about these specifications and limitations?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding a bit on what has been said in some of the comments...

You need to start with a document that tells you what the board(s) is supposed to do, and under what conditions.  This document goes by different names depending on the industry, but a requirements specification is one name that's commonly used.

This documents is full of "shall" statements as in "the XYZ board shall do ABC".  An example for a power supply might be "The XYZ shall provide a 5.0 +/- 0.5 V output over an output current range of 1 A to 5 A".  Note that for a power supply there will probably be many other performance requirements such as ripple/noise, response to step changes in load, over voltage/over current limits, etc.

Then, you need to determine how you're going to verify those requirements, all those "shalls".  For those that you decide to verify through test (note that there are other ways to verify a requirement outside of testing), you need to come up with a test procedure.  For the requirement given above, this might say "Apply a load to the +5V output and vary the load so that the current draw changes from 1 A to 5 A.  Verify that the +5V output remains within specified range."

You then may need to perform this test over your needed operational temperature range, input voltage range (in this case of this hypothetical power supply), and other parameters.

So in your case, you need to have a test setup that mimics what your boards will see in use.  Then you need a way to 1) apply an input voltage that varies over it's specified limits and 2) a way to monitor the current drawn.  You also have to be able tell if your boards are doing what they're supposed to do.